# Automated Website Development like wix.com , edicy.com etc

Tags: php, javascript, asp.net, web

I was just looking at wix.com and edicy.com and it caught my attention that none of these websites let you generate any server side scripts. Why is that there are no drag n drop websites where you can not only change the UI but also add some server side code also?

I have already tried a lot to search for an answer for this, but I still can't figure out why such a service is not there.

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: I can think of a good reason ... why would programmers put themselves out of business? But seriously, one size fits all works for wordpress, but not your awesome idea for a new RESTful twitter-like service. Too many variables. This question is like asking, *"If Dreamweaver exists, why does it cost so much for a professional to build a web site? **Won't Dreamweaver just build it all for you?**"* You might also ask why does it cost so much for a chef to cook a meal in a fine restaurant when everyone already owns a microwave.

Comment: What I meant here was, how come there are soo many websites which let you make your own websites but none of them provides a way for users to create server side components. So, is it that its not possible or is a dead end OR is it that no one has ever tried doing that (which I think would be quite unlikely). I am a website developer myself, and few days back I did a project where a client just needed a simple login/signup system and some good UI. So, my point is, if there are services that lets you make your own website for FREE, why can't they provide with some basic server side components.

Comment: Because a simple login system is only the tip of the iceberg. A login system requires that you have something worth logging in for. Are you going to automate the worthwhile system too? There's just not much of a point to doing it. Also, I don't think this question really fits the **SO** format ... there's no code, no specific right-wrong answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're asking the wrong thing in the wrong place. I think a lot of people here agree with me when I say web development should not be drag and drop, usually what is required is very custom and requires a proper programmer to help you.

Comment: yeah, I am a web developer myself, but my question is regarding the lack of such websites which helps a "non-technical" person to create a website with server side components online. There are a lot of websites which lets you create a "static" website through their online systems without coding, but none of them provides with server side components like a simple login system.

Comment: When you get to that level though, there is never a 'one size fits all' solution. What does the log-in do? Will it have access levels or does that login work for front-end users and back-end users? Is it going to be a CMS system or a facebook/social network site. Or would the login have a billing address and be a shopping cart? And then what customizations after that? I would expect a drag and drop for all solutions to be a nightmare.

Comment: I am not saying that they can cover "all solutions". My point is just that they can start with something basics and may be grow on it to make it more generic that can be used by people with no technical knowledge. So lets just say that a user (who has been using these sites for say his restaurant business to keep a free website running) wants to add a forum where the people can discuss about the food. He'll have to move from these sites, hire a developer to make his website (most of what was free for him till now). Its just that "how come there is no such service already"...

Comment: The closest thing that I can think of would be PHPMaker. It's a program that turns databases you've created into CMS systems. Lots of customization with little to no programming knowledge. Once this 'framework' is generated, anyone with coding knowledge could expand upon it.

Comment: yeah exactly..but isn't PHPmaker a software ?, I am more concerned with a online system which lets you do something similar to UI editing + PHPMaker. Will such a system work? if yes, why isn't it there already... i mean, am I missing something here? because as far as I can see its plausible to build something like this and given that websites like wix.com are popular, such a system can become so too..

Comment: Dunno then, maybe you could build one? Wordpress fills this gap for most people as they can install it and get plugins without programming knowledge.